# /faq#bounty misredirecting

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, unanswered-questions, help-center

The old `/faq#bounty` section discussed how to improve a question and post a bounty, in order to get answers. Its content was essentially the same as the current content of [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/no-one-answers`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/no-one-answers). But `/faq#bounty` now redirects to [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty). The redirect should be fixed in order that old references — as in old comments — to `/faq#bounty` remain relevant.

Comment: Looks like the text for no-one-answers needs to be folded into the bounty page, right at the top.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I actually like the no-one-answers page: it is short and to the point and doesn't unduly emphasize bounties, which is not the primary way of attracting answers. I think the split into two pages should be kept as is.

Comment: Redirecting /faq#bounty to the wrong page doesn't seem like a viable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most of the content in /faq#bounty was devoted to explaining how bounties work, I'm leaving the redirect as it is.

However, to take care of the use case you described, I added the following to the top of /helpcenter/bounty:

> If you’ve [asked a good
>   question](/questions/how-to-ask), [edited it](/helpcenter/editing) with status
>   and progress updates, and still are [not receiving answers](/helpcenter/no-one-answers), you can
>   draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.

Comment: Kudos to the new Help Center; it is very nice.